# Problem with the numbering of figures

Tags: floats, enumerate

I'm trying to use the reference of a figure, but numbering is not correct. Every  figure that I use as a reference, account as Figure 3 and I dont know why. 
I'm using `\documentclass{article}` and this code to insert fist figure:

```
\FloatBarrier 
\begin{figure}[!htp]
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{figura}
\label{fig:fig2}
\caption{Componentes do Sistema Elétrico}
\end{figure}
\FloatBarrier
```

And this code to call figure reference into the paragraph:

```
\paragraph{} Os sistemas [...] elétrica. \figref{fig2} Estes [...] pela Figure~\ref{fig:fig2}.
```

I inserted other figures but always referred to as Figure 3 like I show in picture.[image]

Please, What can I do to solve this  ? =(

Comment: Move `\label{fig:fig2}` after `\caption{}`. Compile twice.

Comment: Or inside `\caption`...

Comment: Its work. Thx friend.